# Select term based on argument values

Tags: list, prolog, compare

I want to compare a value in two lists to find out which one has the smaller one, however as I am a little new to Prolog, I am having some trouble coming up with a suitable procedure for handling this.

I'm trying to check to see if `apple` is cheaper than `cracker` by comparing the numerical value (the last element of each list) in both lists:

```
product(I):-
        I = [_,_,_],
        cheaper(item(apple,fruit,1),item(cracker,biscuit,4)).
```

How should the procedure be designed?

Comment: What is the product rule for? It's incomplete (didn't terminate with a period (`.`)), and seems to only check if `I` is a list with three elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the `I = [_,_,_]` is supposed to do, but you don't need it. Instead, simply:

```
?- cheaper(item(apple,fruit,1), item(cracker,biscuit,4), Cheaper).
Cheaper = item(apple, fruit, 1).

?- cheaper(item(cracker,biscuit,4), item(apple,fruit,1), Cheaper).
Cheaper = item(apple, fruit, 1).
```

It is another question where the two items are coming from, but you should know that better than me.

You just pick out the third argument to each term with unification, and compare them:

```
cheaper(item(I1, K1, P1), item(I2, K2, P2), item(I, K, P)) :-
    (   P1 =< P2
    ->  I = I1, K = K1, P = P1
    ;   I = I2, K = K2, P = P2
    ).
```

Or, if you prefer to do it otherwise:

```
cheaper(I1, I2, Cheaper) :-
    price(I1, P1), price(I2, P2),
    (   P1 =< P2
    ->  Cheaper = I1
    ;   Cheaper = I2
    ).
price(item(_, _, P), P).
```

The help predicate `price/3` is an example of a good method of extracting from a compound term only the argument you need. You could have even called it `item_price/2`, and also, if needed, define `item_name/2` and `item_kind/2`. Or use [`library(record)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record). Or, if you use SWI-Prolog, use [dicts](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts).

Comment: Oddly `?- product(I).` returns `false` when apple should be cheaper than cracker.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without using if statements and ORs.

```
cheaper(item(Name1, _, Price1), item(Name2, _, Price2), Cheapest):- 
    Price1 < Price2,
    Cheapest = Name1.
cheaper(item(Name1, _, Price1), item(Name2, _, Price2), Cheapest):- 
    Price2 < Price1,
    Cheapest = Name2.
```

So it does two separate checks on the prices. Why on Earth would anyone consider that useful? Well what happens when the prices are the same? Should the rule arbitrarily pick the first or second item? Or perhaps it would be better to return `no`, that neither is cheaper than the other (as is the case above). Or maybe it would be better to return both items if they are the same price (see below). That way your calling rule could try the second item if the first couldn't be made to work for whatever reason.

```
cheaper(item(Name1, _, Price1), item(Name2, _, Price2), Cheapest):- 
    Price1 =< Price2,
    Cheapest = Name1.
cheaper(item(Name1, _, Price1), item(Name2, _, Price2), Cheapest):- 
    Price2 =< Price1,
    Cheapest = Name2.

| ?- cheaper(item(apple,fruit,10), item(cucumber,veg,10), Result).
Result = apple ? ;
Result = cucumber ? ;
no
| ?- cheaper(item(chocolate,candy,10), item(cucumber,veg,10), Result), 
     low_calories(Result).
Result = cucumber ? ;
no
```

Comment: `<=` was a copy and paste error on my part. Wrote the code and copied over to prolog when getting the output and forgot to copy the corrections back (I'm using SICStus). Why would this implementation not be stable? The first (top) rule will always be tried first and the second only if the sorting algorithm asks for another answer to the comparison -- which it shouldn't. For efficiency's sake you'd execute a cut inside the sorting algorithm once the list is sorted.